# 'circle' is incompatible with attribute shape (attr) enum [line=2, oval=1, rectangle=0, ring=3]

Tags: android, xml, xamarin.android

I am looking to have a circle in a Xamarin.Android project. I looked up some SO articles and they mentioned using android:shape="circle" which I did. I shows properly in the design preview, but I am unable to build/run the project anymore. I do not want an oval, I need a circle specifically. This is the error:

- 'circle' is incompatible with attribute shape (attr) enum [line=2,
  oval=1, rectangle=0, ring=3]

**axml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="circle">
    <solid android:color="#FFF44444"/>
    <size android:height="1dp" android:width="1dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="30dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only four options we can used for properties `android:shape`.

The options are:

```
  line, oval, rectangle, ring
```

If you want to a circle, you can select `oval` for `android:shape`.

Please refer to the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">
      <solid android:color="#FFF44444"/>
      <size android:height="1dp" android:width="1dp"/>
      <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
      <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:right="30dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

A simple usage:

```
  <ImageView
    android:background="@drawable/myshape"
    android:text="test"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"/>
```

**Update**

> I am able to get the circle, but no text is showing in it.

If you want to add text to the circle, you can use `TextView` and set the `background` for it.

Please refer to the following code:

```
<TextView 
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/myshape"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="1"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"/>
```

Comment: Hi @Jessie . I am able to get the circle, but no text is showing in it. Its just a red circle, even though I have android:text="test" per your solution. I tried changing the textColor but that did not help either.

Comment: Hi @angleUr, I have updated my answer. You check the updated part at the bottom of my reply.